# struct with multiple char arrays problem

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Why is output of this code

```
1234567890asdfg
asdfg
```

(i can't use string class)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct S
{
 char a[10];
 char b[20];
};

int main()
{
 struct S* test = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));

 strcpy(test->a, "1234567890");
 strcpy(test->b, "asdfg");

 printf("%s\n%s", test->a, test->b);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question as C, but are you actually compiling this with a C++ compiler? You mention the string class, and your struct would have to be referred to as `struct S`, not just `S`, in C.

Comment: Yeah iam using MVC++. Thx for warning about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string you've put in `test->a` is eleven characters long including the terminating null character: `1234567890\0`. When you copy it into `a`, that null character ends up in the first character of `b`. You then overwrite it with the string you copy into `b`, so that in memory you have:

```
a - - - - - - - - - b - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a s d f g \0
                    ^
                    |
        a's terminating null was here.
```

You then print `a` (starting from the `'1'`), and `b` (starting from the `'a'`), producing that output.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"1234567890"` actually needs 11 byte (`char`s).

So that you overwrite the first character of `b`.